# System $\,x+y+z=1\,$ and $\,\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1$

Tags: polynomials, contest-math, systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I'm trying to solve the following system of equations:

I. $\,x+y+z=1$

II. $\,\frac{1}{x}+\frac{1}{y}+\frac{1}{z}=1$

And an elegant solution just eludes me.
It should be a rather easy problem, but I'm having slight problems solving it.
I tried just brute force substituting it, but didn't seem to get anywhere with that approach either...

Comment: This is indeterminate, what do you expect ?

Comment: Since there are 2 equations and 3 unknowns, you likely have an infinite number of solutions.  Two ways of getting solutions jump out, both from the fact it is clear that $x,y,z$ cannot all have the same sign:

(1) Let $ x=-y$

(2) Let $z=\pm ax$, $y=\pm bx$ for certain $a,b$.

Comment: Similar problem but with 1 more equation given in the system: https://artofproblemsolving.com/community/c6h1231569p6227478

Comment: [$\frac1x+\frac1y=\frac{1}{x+y-1}+1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-1%2F%28x+%2B+y+-+1%29+%2B+1%2Fx+%2B+1%2Fy+-+1%3D0) factorizes as $-\frac{(x - 1) (y - 1) (x + y)}{x y (x + y - 1)} = 0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, this is an indeterminate system of equations. However we can still solve for a general form of the solutions. Notice that $\dfrac1x+ \dfrac1y+ \dfrac1z=\dfrac{xy+yz+xz}{xyz}$, by Vieta's theorem for cubic equations we may construct an equation in t which has solutions $t= x,y,$ or $z$.

$t^3-t^2-a^2t+a^2=0\implies (t^2-a^2)(t-1)=0$ , where a is an arbitrary constant.

So $t=a, -a$ (these two solution exhibits the non-negativity restriction on $a^2$ if you're solving in $\Bbb R$), or $t=1$.

Set $x=a,y=-a, z=1$, and you have a set of solutions.

Edit: Made the substitution $A=-a^2$ as suggested by Yves in the comments.

Comment: What about writing $-a^2$ rather than $A$ ?

Comment: @YvesDaoust Works. I'll change it

Answer (score 1):

We have $$xy+xz+yz=xyz,$$ which gives
$$(xy+xz+yz)(x+y+z)=xyz$$ or
$$(x+y)(x+z)(y+z)=0.$$
Let $x+y=0$.

Thus, $z=1$ and we see that it gives solutions as $(t,-t,1)$, where $t\neq0$.

The cases $x+z=0$ and $y+z=0$ are similar.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{cases}y+z=1-x,\\\dfrac{y+z}{yz}=1-\dfrac1x\end{cases}$$

implies

$$yz=-x.$$

Then

$$y^2+yz=(1-x)y$$

and

$$y^2-(1-x)y-x=0.$$

Solve for $y$ as a function of $x$ and you are done.

Comment: It ignores the case when $y+z=0$, in which case the first implication $yz=-x$ cannot be made

Comment: @MadhuchhandaMandal: that's right.